# Is there any way I can import to Sequel Pro?

Tags: mysql, import, sequelpro

I have four files (.ldf; .mdf; fdb;.fbk)-files that I have to import to MySql using Sequel Pro. Is it possible for me to import those type of files and if not could it work with MySQL Workbench?

Comment: These are files used by Microsoft SQL Server. Your best best is to export the data from MS SQL server in SQL form, then load them into MySQL.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I use Mac so I haven't windows at home. I'm thinking downloading Oracle sql Developer and maybe do it that way? OR maybe I should ask a friend which have MS SQL and do it for me.

Comment: I have to say that it is a little bit wierd because my teacher has said that the files are runnable on every system.